# always getting crash issue when trying to receive string value from TCP Server-Client

Tags: android, c++, tcpclient, tcpserver

i always getting crash issue when trying to receive string value from TCP Server-Client, can someone fix it??

```
struct request_data_t {
    int Mode;
    bool boolean;
    int value;
    std::string fileName;
    std::string content;
};

size_t TCPServer::receive(void *outData) {
    uint32_t length = 0;
    int code = receive_data(&length, sizeof(uint32_t));
    if (code > 0) {
        length = ntohl(length);
        receive_data(outData, static_cast<size_t>(length));
    }
    return length;
}

int TCPServer::receive_data(void *outData, size_t size) {
    char *buffer = static_cast<char *>(outData);
    int numReceived = 0;

    while (size) {
        do {
            numReceived = read(new_socket, buffer, size);
        } while (numReceived == -1 && errno == EINTR);

        if (numReceived <= 0) {
            close(server_fd);
            break;
        }

        size -= numReceived;
        buffer += numReceived;
    }
    return numReceived;
}

size_t TCPServer::send(void *inData, size_t size) {
    uint32_t length = htonl(size);
    int code = send_data(&length, sizeof(uint32_t));
    if(code <= 0){

        return 0;
    }
    return send_data(inData, size);
}

size_t TCPServer::send_data(void *inData, size_t size) {
    char *buffer = static_cast<char *>(inData);
    int numSent = 0;

    while (size) {
        do {
            numSent = write(new_socket, buffer, size);
        } while (numSent == -1 && errno == EINTR);

        if (numSent <= 0) {
            close(server_fd);
            break;
        }

        size -= numSent;
        buffer += numSent;
    }
    return numSent;
}

void TCPServer::SendData(int Mode, bool boolean, int value, const char* fileName, const char* content) {

    request_data_t request{};
    request.Mode = Mode;
    request.boolean = boolean;
    request.value = value;

    request.fileName = fileName;
    request.content = content;

    send((void*)&request,sizeof(request));
}
```

i want it able to send string value and then able to receive the string, i want the result looks like this

TCPServer server;
server.SendData(11, true, 20, "test.txt", "hello");

TCPClient client;

request_data_t2 received_data;
client.receive((void *)&received_data);

LOGD("fileName: %s", received_data.fileName.c_str()); // but always crash here when i try to call received_data.fileName and received_data.content

Comment: `send((void*)&request,sizeof(request));` -- TL;DR.  Your `request_data_t` struct is not trivially-copyable.  Also, this could never work.  What is `sizeof(request)`?  It is a compile-time value that never changes, regardless of what `fileName` and `content` have as data.  You need to send the *data* that `request_data_t` represents, not the object.  That detail is called *object serialization*.

Comment: [See this](https://godbolt.org/z/1j586EoEM).  See the difference in what is trivially copyable and what isn't?  The `request_data_t` contains `std::string` members, and those cannot be copied as if they are just blobs of bytes.  Also, [this may be a duplicate](/questions/23176758/how-do-i-save-and-load-a-stdstring-with-object-serialization-in-c).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it works, but there is a way to make it without fixed size for `char fileName[100];` and `char content[100];`?

Comment: Look at the link in the second comment.  You need to send the *data* that the string object represents.  That could be the length, followed by the data.  Note that your issue is the same as the one in the link, with the only difference is that the @OP at the link is doing this: `ofstream_obj.write((char *)&PC, sizeof(Actor));`, which will not work, and you are doing this: `send((void*)&request,sizeof(request));`, which will also not work.  Both examples are erroneously taking a non-trivial object and assuming they can just write/send the object as-is, which is wrong.